# Initializing a struct with the contents of a std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

This seems like something that should be simple and straightforward, but Google turns up very little.

What’s a clean, modern (C++11) way of initializing a simple file header struct like the following

```
typedef struct FooHeader {
    uint8_t    FooCount;
    uint8_t    BarCount;
    uint32_t   BazOffsets[4];
} FooHeader;
```

with the data contained in a `std::vector<unsigned char>`? Is it a good idea to create a sub vector and cast its data to the header struct type, or?

Comment: Are you assuming your usage can safely ignore potential platform endianness and structure packing issues and simply assume all readers *and* writers share the same concept for *both*? That is, honestly, the thing that makes such activity tedious.

Comment: Yes I am, as the file format is already well-established and all applications working with it thus far have agreed on how it should be read and written. It’s also highly unlikely that this software will see use on any platform other than x86.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to create a subvector? Also, do you have a single FooHeader variable in your program, or std::vector<FooHeader> that you want to fill using std::vector<unsigned char>?

Comment: If I don’t have to create a subvector, I won’t. It was just a thought. In this case, FooHeader would be a local variable.

Comment: How about `FooHeader h = *(reinterpret_cast<FooHeader*>(&data_vec[0]))`?

Comment: That certainly works, but is that really better than a regular old C style cast? Also, isn’t it best to avoid working directly with memory addresses when possible?

Comment: You're looking for a one-line catch-all solution that does not (and cannot) exist. Sometimes (often, actually) you can't just try a few "Google searches", say "nothing comes up" and give up. You have to apply _thought_, and _reasoning_. Days of planning and design. In short, don't be so lazy!

Comment: You’re absolutely right, Lightness Races in Orbit. That said, my current experience with C++ is quite minimal which leaves me paranoid of falling into bad practices, and I feel like the only surefire way of avoiding that, save for more experience, is to call on those who are already seasoned. If there is a “right way”, I greatly prefer to learn that before anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid running into packing, alignment and endianness issues, it is best to read the data at the byte level (on almost all modern hardware, you can assume 8-bit bytes, but packing often changes between compilers (or even just between different compilation flags) and both big and little endian computers are still common).

This means that your best bet is something like:

```
FooHeader load_FooHeader(std::vector<unsigned char> const &dat) {
    static_assert(
        std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits == 8,
        "Assumes 8-bit bytes");

    FooHeader retv;

    retv.FooCount = dat[0];
    retv.BarCount = dat[1];

    //Start at the fifth byte, to allow for padding.
    //If you want to use a packed format, use index = 2;
    std::size_t index{4};
    for (std::size_t i{0}, iend{4}; i < iend; ++i) {
        retv.BarOffsets[i] = 0;
        //Adjust ordering depending on desired endianness.
        //Currently uses little endian.
        for (std::size_t j{0}, jend{4}; j < jend; ++j) {
            retv.BarOffsets[i] |= dat[index + i*4 + (3-j)] << (j*8);
        }
    }

    return retv;
}
```